# How to update the query in parse?

Tags: android, parsing

How can I update a Number row in Parse (data Browser) using Android?

My code so far:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("theClassWithNames");
 query.whereEqualTo("TheNameIWant", nameWriten.getText().toString());
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> nameList, ParseException e) 
{
  if (e == null) 
  {     
          for (ParseObject nameObj : nameList)
          {
               nameObj.put("TheAgeRow", one);
          }
  } 
  else 
  {
          Log.d("Post retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
  });
```

one - is an int with a number.

TheAgeRow - is the number row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
nameObj.put("TheAgeRow", one);
nameObj.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Thx mate, i missed that saveInBackground();